# Equivalance between a set $ S_m $ and $ \mathbb{Z}_m $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**

Let $$ {S_m} = \left\{ \left[ \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \right]_{\pmod{m}} \mid k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}.$$ Show that $ S_m = \mathbb{Z}_m $ if and only if $ m = 2^s $ for some $ s \in \mathbb{N}.$

**Attempted solution:**

First I want to show that if $ S_m = \mathbb{Z}_m $, then $ m = 2^s $ for some $ s.$

If $ a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $ n \mid m $ then $ a \equiv b \pmod{n}$. So this gives that if $S_m = \mathbb{Z}_m $ and $ n \mid m$, then $S_n = \mathbb{Z}_n$.

I want to use that the squares $ \pmod n $ takes at most $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ distinct values. I got a hint at my previous post that if $ n $ is odd,  then $8$ is invertible modulo $n$ and $$8^{-1}\left((2k+1)^2-1\right)\equiv \frac{k(k+1)}2\pmod n$$

The squares modulo $n$ take at most $(n+1)/2$ distinct values, and thus $\frac{k(k+1)}2$ modulo $n$ can take at most $(n+1)/2$ distinct values. Thus, when $n>1$ is odd, though can’t have $S_n=\mathbb Z_n.$

I get why 8 is invertible (gcd(8,n) = 1) and the $\equiv $ relation, ***but I don't see the square at left hand side?***

However, assuming this is true, then $ m $ can't be odd or have an odd prime factor, so $ m = 2^s $.

Other way around with induction:

The basis is trivial for $ m = 2 $.

Assume that $ S_{2^s} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^s} $. Then we want to show that $ S_{2^{s+1}} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^{s+1}} $. Since $ 2^s \mid 2^{s+1} $ and $ S_{2^s} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^s} $ by assumption, then $ S_{2^{s+1}} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^{s+1}} $.

***Is this correct?***

Muchos gracias!